# Using awk on shell variable with delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to take a string from a shell variable as an input and print the second word using awk

I'm not sure why this doesn't work

```
ITEM="ABC DEF"
awk -v var=$ITEM -F ' ' '{ print $2 }'
```

The result should be DEF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ item="ABC DEF"
$ awk '{print $2}' <<< "$item"
DEF
```

`$2` is the second field of the input line. But there is no input. Use `<<<` to redirect the variable `$item` on `awk`'s standard input.

Maybe easier to understand would be to use `echo`:

```
$ echo "$item" | awk '{print $2}'
DEF
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ITEM="ABC DEF"
$ awk -v var="$ITEM" 'BEGIN{ split(var,a); print a[2] }'
DEF
```

but also consider:

```
$ a=( $ITEM )
$ echo "${a[1]}"
DEF
```

and:

```
$ set -- $ITEM
$ echo "$2"
DEF
```

Those last 2 may need to be sanitized for globbing, etc. depending on the values in ITEM.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this task could be done with parameter expansion itself like as follows.

```
echo "${ITEM#* }"
DEF
```

Off course if you have any further requirements then other programs could be considered too here.

Answer (score 1):

As nicely explained by `PesaThe`, you could use

```
$ echo "$item" | awk '{print $2}'
DEF
```

however I feel that using awk for printing a part of variable is an **overkill**. 
You could go for an easier solution like `cut` command:

```
$ echo "$item" | cut -d' ' -f2
DEF
```

where you defined the separator as space using `-d' '` and you select the second field using `-f2`